# Uploading and Downloading Comparison using WebRequest & Sockets

Tags: c#, networking, ftp

Hiya I am working on an FTP client, can someone tell me the difference in speed and efficiency for using `WebRequest` and sockets (direct network streams) to download and upload files on the FTP server. (Our files will be video streams.) 
I am using C#3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is without the benefit of extensive testing but I've used both methods in the past.  WebRequest does some inheriting from the Stream class and is really just a convenient wrapper for doing the sort of work you're up to.  Any losses you might face could, I think, be written off as negligible. Perhaps a tiny amount of RAM at worst.  Enjoy the extra functionality, thats why it was created.